# Chrome driver force stop loading and disable flash

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In using Chrome driver and selenium, below script is to open a page.

[image]

The annoying thing is, sometimes (not always) it keeps loading and never stop. So I added lines to force stop the loading.

Besides that, I disabled the showing of image and flash. However, these measures are not very effective. (I also uninstalled the flash on the computer. But it seems like the flash is still being shown)

Is it because the flash showing delay the page loading? If it is, what's the best way to force stop the loading, and stop the flash shown on this page? Thank you.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chromedriver = "D:\\Python27\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

options= webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2, "plugins.plugins_disabled": ["Adobe Flash Player"]}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options =options, desired_capabilities=capa)

driver.get("https://www.investing.com/crypto/bitcoin/btc-usd")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 2)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'topBarPopup')))
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")

time.sleep(60)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't find any flash on that page... And btw it could just because your network is slow. As it looks like these two fragments come from other sites. Try to check your connection speed to `i-invdn-com.akamaized.net`?

Comment: @Sraw,  Thank you for the comment. As there's no flash on the page. What are those two red line circled images? How can I disable them? Thanks.